# JAXB class with specific @XmlAttribute value

Tags: jaxb

I am trying to create JAXB classes to only filter out Product of type Item
irrespective the item is present in which category.

```
<Product usertype="category1">
   <Product usertype="category2">
     <Product usertype="Item">
     .....
     ....
     </Product>
 </Product>
</Product>
```

AM not sure if we can provide value in @XmlAttribute(name = "usertype") in jaxb classes.

Please let us know how we can proceed in above unusual scenario

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse xml based on attributes using JAXB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586106/parse-xml-based-on-attributes-using-jaxb)

Comment: thanks, but am facing issue with same nested tag name instead of having at same level

Comment: is it possible to ignore all the elements and just filtered out <Product usertype="Item">?
Current the top elements are dynamic in nature... means it may have 1 or 2 or 3 hierarchy of Product element